# retornar a query como string do zend

Tags: php, sql, pdo, zend, zend-framework-2

tenho o seguinte codigo onde preciso guardar dentro da variavel $erro_itens a query completa com os parametros para analisar o que está acontecendo, minha duvida é, como faço para mostrar essa query?

```
$sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
                $query = $sql->insert('reg_c170');
                $query->values($prod);
                $erro_itens = $queryAqui; // preciso ver a query
                $myitens = fopen("./data/log/".date('Y-m-d')."-itens-add.log", "a+");
                fwrite($myitens, $erro_itens."\r\n");
                fclose($myitens);
```

Comment: Tente `print_r($query->__toString());`.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que tu possa usar:

```
$query->getSqlString($this->dbAdapter->getPlatform());
```

partindo do principio que tu está dentro de um ZendDbSql

[Referência](https://akrabat.com/displaying-the-generated-sql-from-a-zenddbsql-object/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = $select->getSqlString();
```

Sendo que `$select` é um `object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select)[421]`